# Odd number of momentum should vanish but doesn't?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, integration, dimensional-regularization

I have the following integral found within a loop-calculation (the actual content of the Feyman diagram, this is purely a math question)
\begin{equation}
J_\mu = \int\frac{d^4l}{(2\pi)^4}\frac{l_\mu}{l^2(l+q)^2}.
\end{equation}

Now the paper this is quoted from says this integral is equal to
\begin{equation}
\frac{i}{32\pi^2}(q_\mu\ln(-q^2))+\cdots
\end{equation}
But I see a huge glaring issue which is the numerator is odd w.r.t. momentum but the denominator is even, and thus should vanish. Now, a small note would be that, "this integral has a covariant momentum $l_\mu$," but couldn't I just change $l_\mu = \eta_{\mu\alpha}l^\alpha$, pull out the factor of the metric (which is in Minkowski signature), and then I have an integral that is stated it vanishes within the appendix of lets say Peskin & Schroeder? It is because it is massless? I am at a lost here.

EDIT: if I add a mass-term to each momentum, i.e $l^2\rightarrow l^2 - m^2$ and $(l-q)^2\rightarrow (l-q)^2 - m^2$, then would it vanish?

Any technical clarification is helpful, thanks.

Comment: I think the answer to your question here is merely that, while it _looks_ like it should be zeroed by an argument over the odd-ness v.s. even-ness of the integrand, it is just that you have made a tiny mistake. The denominator is not symmetric as it is; but can be made symmetric with a simple change. The integrand is actually$$\frac{[(\ell+\frac12q)-\frac12q]_\mu}{[(\ell+\frac12q)-\frac12q]^2[(\ell+\frac12q)+\frac12q]^2}=\frac{[(\ell+\frac12q)-\frac12q]_\mu}{[(\ell+\frac12q)^2-(\frac12q)^2]^2}=\frac{p_\mu}{[p^2+c^2]^2}-\frac{c_\mu}{[p^2+c^2]^2}$$and an even integrand appears.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent but what if I had the masses included, and performed dim-reg on  it using the Feynman trick, and put the integrand in the form of $l/(l-\Delta)^2$? This would then be an integral I can argue vanishes, correct? (I also agree with you). I think me shifting the integral with the Feynman trick is similar to what you are doing, so then I would be left with an odd/even situation.

Comment: If the mass is the same everywhere, i.e. same on both squares in the denominator, then the trick I did will proceed the same way with minimal changes. This means that it will NOT vanish. The argument you are making is just wrong; you think you have made things (skew-)symmetric, but actually it is not yet so. You have to do it the way I suggested in order to actually achieve the (skew-)symmetry, and then you can discard those with odd integrands.

Comment: In particular, $[\ell^2\pm m^2]^2$ is symmetric, whereas $[\ell\pm\Delta]^2$ is NOT symmetric about $\ell=0$

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent so for example, if I had an integrand of $l_\mu l_\nu l_\alpha/((l^2-m^2)((l-q)^2 - m^2))$ this wouldn't necessarily vanish or I couldn't until until after the Feynman trick of $1/AB = \cdots$?

Comment: I am not at all using Feynman's trick. That complicated example of yours will not vanish, using the trick or not, because it is not actually skew-symmetric. You are using the important concept wrongly.

Comment: Which paper? Which page?

Comment: "but the denominator is even..." No, it isn't.

Comment: Denominator is NOT even dude. Under $\ell \to - \ell$, we have $(\ell + q)^2 \to ( \ell - q )^2 \boldsymbol{\neq} ( \ell + q)^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First by use of the Feynmann parameters we write
$$J_{\mu}=\int_{0}^{1}dx\int\frac{d^4 l}{(2\pi)^4}\frac{l_{\mu}}{(xl^2+(1-x)(l+q)^2)^2}$$
Completing the square in the downstairs gives:
$$J_{\mu}=\int_{0}^{1}dx\int\frac{d^4 l}{((2\pi)^4}\frac{l_{\mu}}{(l+(1-x) q)^2+x(1-x)q^2)^2}$$
Now we define $l+(1-x) q=k$, then
$$J_{\mu}=\int_{0}^{1}dx\int\frac{d^4 k}{(2\pi)^4}\frac{k_{\mu}-(1-x)q_{\mu}}{(k^2+x(1-x)q^2)^2}$$
Now, we have two integrals over $k$, the first, namely $\int k_{\mu}$, vanishes due to a reason like what you mentioned, and we are left with
$$J_{\mu}=\int_{0}^{1}dx\big(-(1-x)q_{\mu}\big)\int\frac{d^4 k}{(2\pi)^4}\frac{1}{(k^2+x(1-x)q^2)^2}$$
Now as you said, From Peskin-Schroeder Appendix, we have
$$J_{\mu}=\int_{0}^{1}dx\big(-(1-x)q_{\mu}\big)\big(\frac{i}{(4\pi)^2}\big(-\log(-x(1-x)q^2)+\cdots\big)$$
which gives
$$J_{\mu}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{i}{(4\pi)^2}q_{\mu} \log(-q^2)+\cdots$$
Hope this helps.

Comment: Well, this is definitely right, it just looks like I'll have to go back through a derivation of mine and find a few integral I missed.... thanks!

Comment: Where did the pole structure of $1/\epsilon$ go in the $\Gamma(x)$ expansion?

Comment: @MathZilla After performing the Integral you need to renormalize your physical quantity J_{\mu}. As an example, see (7.90) in Peskin-Schroeder. \Pi(q^2) there is not physical. According to (7.77), the physical quantity is given by (7.91). And here is the place where 1/epsilon disappears. In your case you need to define something like J_{\mu}(q^2)-J_{\mu}(0) as the renormalized physical quantity.